# selectors in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to select a link which is inside `table tr td`

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href=""></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is my selector, but it is not working:

```
$(table#id tr>td>a.linkid);
```

Comment: Does your table have ID `id`? Does the link have the class `.linkid`? You have to pass a string to jQuery. Please make sure that you post at least syntactically correct code.

Comment: I can't tell what you are really after.  Do you want the value of the `href` attribute in the `<a>` element? Or do you want the `<a>` element itself?

Comment: @Felix Kling.yep my table and link inside td has an id.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/bncas/

```
<table>
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Title </th>
     <th>Title 2</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td><a href='http://somesite.com'></a></td>
     <td><a class='linkid' href='http://correctsite.com'></a></td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

$('td a.linkid').each(function(){
   $(this);// reference to link
});

$('td a.linkid:first'); //reference to first link
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("table#id > a.linkid");
```

See jQuery child selector [here](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

Comment: I see your edited your question. I still assume your table has an id (id) and your link contains a class (linkid)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an id on the link you can just write `$('#linkID');`

Or you can try jQuery `find()`: http://api.jquery.com/find/